# Every Ring is Isomorphic to a Subring of an Endomorphism Ring of an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Show that for every ring $(R,+,\cdot)$, there is an abelian group, $(A,+)$, such that $R$ is isomorphic to a subring of $(\operatorname{End}(A),+,\circ)$.

$(\operatorname{End}(A),+,\circ)$ is the set of homomorphisms of $A$ that form a ring under function addition and composition.

I am thinking to let $\operatorname{End}(A)$ be the group such that $A$ is the abelian group $(R,+)$ and create a ring homomorphism from $(R,+,\cdot)$ into $\operatorname{End}((R,+))$.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: For future visitors, it should be remarked for that any (unital, associative) ring $A$, the below map (sending an element $a$ to a (left-)$A$-linear map $A\to A$) is *almost* an isomorphism; it is an isomorphism from the opposite ring $A^{op}$ to $End_A(A)$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270614/for-a-ring-r-does-operatornameend-rr-cong-r-mathrmop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct, (madame or) sir.

This is essentially the ring-theoretic analogue of [Cayley's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) for groups.

Also, this issue (as a question) [came up a while back on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27971/why-is-there-no-cayleys-theorem-for-rings).

**Added**: I had missed that the explicit definition of the map was not contained in the OP's question.  A natural ring embedding from $R$ to $\operatorname{End}(R,+)$ is

$r \mapsto \bullet r: (x \in R \mapsto xr)$.

[Or possibly $r \mapsto r \bullet: (x \in R \mapsto rx)$, depending upon your conventions on composition.]

Comment: What homomorphism can I use from $(R,+,\cdot)$ to $End((R,+))$?

Comment: @neelp: what options do you have? A ring has two operations. One of them is addition. And the other one is...

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using $(R,+)$ as the candidate abelian group, you should use
$$
A = \oplus_{a\in R}A_a
$$
where $A_a$ is the cyclic group generated by the element $a$.

Let $f \in End(A)$. Then we can think of $f$ as
$$
\oplus_{a\in R}f_a
$$
where $f_a \in End(A_a)$.

Finally, we can define a map $\phi: R \rightarrow End(A)$ such that for $b \in R$
$$
\phi(b) = \oplus_{a\in R}f_a
$$
where $f_a$ is the trivial map if $a \neq b$;
and $f_a$ is the identity map if $a = b$.

Comment: Why don't you want to use $(R,+)$?

Comment: I cannot see an obvious map from $R$ into $End(R)$

Comment: @Hongshan: how about $r : x \mapsto rx$?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: of course. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider $(R,+)$, the underlying abelian group. Then, an injective morphism is
\begin{align*}
\lambda:R&\to \text{End}_{\textsf{Ab}}(R)\\
r&\mapsto \lambda_r
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_r$ is left-multiplication by $r$.