# For a ring $R$, does $\operatorname{End}_R(R)\cong R^{\mathrm{op}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Given a ring $R$, how to prove that $\operatorname{End}_R(R)\cong R^{\mathrm{op}}$, where $R^{\mathrm{op}}$ is the opposite ring of $R$.

I read this proposition somewhere, but I think it is wrong. Because for any given $f\in\operatorname{End}_R(R) $ and any $r$ in $R$, we can get $f(r)$ by $r f(1)$, and $f(1)$can only be $1$, so $\operatorname{End}_R(R)$ is isomorphic to the trivil group.

Is there anything wrong with my logic? Please help me identify where I am wrong in my understanding of $\operatorname{End}_R(R)$. Thanks!

Comment: The subscript $R$ to End is there to remind you that one is not talking about (unitary) ring endomorphisms; if one was, what would that subscript mean? Instead these are endomorphisms as $R$-modules, the context should determine whether left or right modules are meant.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not the case that $f(1)$ must be $1$. A map in $\mathrm{End}_R(R)$ is (a) linear and (b) commutes with multiplication (on the left) from $R$. These are *not* ring endomorphisms (which must satisfy the multiplicative property $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$, but do not enjoy full $R$-linearity, only linearity over the prime subgring generated by $1_R$), but rather *left $R$-module* endomorphisms.

Thus, every element of $\mathrm{End}_RR$ has $f(r)=f(r\cdot1_R)=rf(1_R)$ and hence is right multiplication by some $a\in R$. Furthermore, if $\varphi_a:x\mapsto xa$ for every $a\in R$, then

$$\varphi_a\varphi_b(x)=\varphi_a(xb)=xba=\varphi_{ba}(x)$$

and hence $a\bullet_{\small\mathrm{End}_RR}b=ba$ (after identifying the underlying sets of $\mathrm{End}_RR$ and $R$).

Thus $\mathrm{End}_RR\cong R^{\,\rm op}$.

Answer (score 4):

$End_R(R)$ denotes the map of $R$-module endomorphisms of $R.$ So the condition that map takes $1$ to $1$ is not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

When one writes $End _{R} (R)$ what is meant most of the time is the ring of $R$-*module homomorphisms* $R \rightarrow R$. That is, those $f: R \rightarrow R$ that are additive and satisfy $f(ra) = rf(a)$. (Such a homomorphisms need not take $1$ to $1$).

Indeed, *ring endomorphisms* $R \rightarrow R$ do not form a ring in any natural way, since a sum of two ring endomorphisms need not be a rign endomorphism again.

Answer (score 2):

I'll just make two observations that I missed in other answers.

First, if $\def\End{\operatorname{End}}\End(R)$ were to denote the set of unitary ring endomorphisms, then each of its elements has to map $1$ to $1$, but that does not force them to be the identity of$~R$. Much depends on the nature of$~R$. It can be or more or less large (Galois) group, but in general is is only a monoid. For $R=K[X]$ it is in bijection with $R$ itself (but the monoid structure is not that of the multiplicative monoid), it can be larger still.

Second, if $\End_R(R)$ denotes the endomorphisms as $R$ as a module over itself, we need to specify in the non-commutative case whether we consider the left or right module structure; the opposite in the isomorphism $\End_R(R)\cong R^{op}$ is not a fatality, but an artefact of the wish to have scalars act on the same side as module morphisms. But it is more natural to have then act from *opposite* sides, as morphisms must commute with scalars, and in the non-commutative (but associative) setting this is the case for multiplications from different sides. So, taking morphisms to apply from the left as usual, we can let $\End_R(R)$ denote the ring of right $R$-module endomorphisms of $R$, and then one has $\End_R(R)\cong R$ with $f\mapsto f(1)$ in one direction and $a\mapsto(x\mapsto ax)$ in the other direction.