# Group Automorphisms of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $(k,+)$ be the additive group. I have read somewhere that the group automorphisms of $(k,+)$ are exactly the multiplications by non-zero elements of $k$. I am a little bit confused by this. For example, if $k = \mathbb C$, then the conjugation map is a group automorphism, but it is not a multiplication by a non-zero element.

It is clear that any multiplication by a non-zero element is an automorphism. Conversely, any automorphism $\phi$ will have the following properties: $\phi(0) = 0$ and $ \phi(n\cdot 1) = n\cdot\phi(1)$, for any $n\in\mathbb Z$. Moreover, if $\phi$ is a polynomial, then $\phi(x) = ax+b$, and the first property implies that $b = 0$, so $\phi(x) = ax$. But I don't know how to generalize this. I know some proofs of similar result for the real numbers, with additional properties, e.g. the function is order-preserving or measurable, but these proofs use analysis, which is not useful here.

Any help with my confusion or how to prove this result would be appreciated!

Comment: What **is** true, however: The [ring of $R$-module endomorphisms of $R$ is $R^{\rm op}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270614/operatornameend-rr-cong-rop/), which in our case, since everything is abelian, means that the $\bf C$-module automorphisms (of $\bf C$) are ${\bf C}^\times$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Chris says, the claimed result is false. And *very* false: the *only* field of characteristic zero for which all additive automorphisms are multiplications by a nonzero element is $\mathbb Q$. Since any other field $K$ of characteristic zero is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ of dimension greater than $1$, there will always be (for instance) permutations of the basis that fail to accord with a multiplication.

Now, if you bring in continuity, the story becomes rather different. But you evidently know that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no, I don't know what happen when we bring continuity.

Comment: Well, if $\phi\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous homomorphism, and (say) $\phi(1)=a$, then $\phi(m/n)=(m/n)a$, as you’ve recognized. But this map $\phi_0$ on $\mathbb Q$ is continuous (for the order topology on $\mathbb Q$), indeed uniformly so, thus extends uniquely to $\mathbb R$, thus the extension is your original map $\phi$. So a continuous additive self-map of $\mathbb R$ is a multiplication, by $a$ in this case.

Comment: Oh I see thank you. I thought you meant some kind of continuity for general fields, which did not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The claimed result is false, as you have observed: complex conjugation is an automorphism of $(\Bbb{C},+)$ that is not multiplication by a complex number.

Comment: I see, thanks! Do you know if there are any additional assumptions making this statement true?

Comment: Well, it's true if $k$ is a prime field. That isn't very interesting though.

Comment: @Chris: True, and also conversely: every nonprime field $k$ is a vector space over its prime subfield $k_0$ of dimension greater than one.  Thus you can choose a $k_0$-basis of $k$ consisting of $1$ and at least one other basis element $b$, and it follows that there is a $k_0$-linear automorphism $\varphi$ of $k$ (in particular, an automorphism of the additive group) such that $\varphi(b) \neq b \varphi(1)$.  In particular, the property never holds for an algebraically closed field, as the OP asked.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark That makes for a novel characterization of prime fields.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be helpful:
maybe see the field as an extension of some field. For example $\mathbb{R}$ is a 
$\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so taking a 
$\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$ and the map sending every element of the basis to other element of this basis will be a group 
automrphism

Comment: No, it's true for $k=\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: you´re right. I see if i can think something more useful

Comment: maybe see the field as an extension of some field. For example $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so taking a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$ and the map sending every element of the basis to other element of this basis will be a group automrphism