# Is every ring a homomorphic image of some abelian group's endomorphism ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Is every ring a homomorphic image of some abelian group's endomorphism ring?

I ask because I've never liked to identify rings as being subrings of endomorphism rings.  A subring is basically a ring within another ring, so if you answer "what is natural about the ring axioms (and by extension, rings as a whole)" with "because they are (essentially) subrings of an endomorphism ring", then to me it feels like saying "rings are naturals because they are rings"... well yes, but why those axioms?

I'm a beginner in ring theory. I don't know if this is true and google didn't really help me out here.

Comment: Endomorphism of whatsits? Every ring can be realized as a *subring* of the endomorphism ring of its underlying abelian group...

Comment: Besides the trivial way, where $R\cong End(R_R)$?

Comment: Working on a question whose truth/falsity you are not sure of is like the purest form of doing math there is. I'm not going to do it, but I was tempted to try to close this question with a reason of "This will build character". :-)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC oh I know. In general I love working on problems when I don't know how the answer will turn out. I hate how in school they always say "show that X" and essentially, in the process, give you the answer. I even like to attempt problems I will have no chance in solving, but I love to give it my all anyways. Right now I'm just trying to get a quick "bird's eye view of the subject (and some things I want to know about)", so to speak, but later I will return thoroughly. Thank you for being honest.

Comment: @rschwieb wait, there's a trivial way?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin actually this was one of my motivations for asking this question; I've never liked to identify rings as being *subrings* of endomorphism rings, because a subring is basically a ring within another ring. So if you answer "what is natural about the ring axioms (and by extension, rings as a whole)" with "because they are (essentially) subrings of an endomorphism ring" to me it feels like saying "rings are naturals because they are rings"... well yes, but why those axioms?

Comment: (-con't) Anyways, I wish I could give a give a less jumbled explanation of my thoughts on that, but I'm one of those people where if I don't get around to it now it'll never happen. Just didn't want let this to go *completely* unaddressed, for the information of anyone reading this question, because you bring up a good point.

Comment: @pineapplefish https://math.stackexchange.com/a/431083

Comment: @rschwieb Wouldn't the identity need to be $R=\operatorname{End}(R_{\Bbb Z})$ (see Arturo's comment in that regard) in order for your remark to answer the question?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio At the time I commented, it wasn’t clear what kind of endomorphism ring was meant.  In fact I think it’s still true now.  $end(R_R)$ is an endomorphism ring in my estimation.  I don’t see that Arturos comment contradicts my idea: in fact I made my comment for the same reason Arturo made his.  Are we talking about endomorphisms of groups? Modules? Nobody knows.

Comment: @PineappleFish Can you clarify soon? Otherwise many will feel this question needs to be closed for clarification, to try to force your hand to clarify.

Comment: @rschwieb I'm such a beginner I didn't even know until a second ago that you could even have endomorphism rings for things other than abelian groups. Thanks so much! I would've clarified I just didn't there was anything *to* clarify. I knew something looked strange about that $\text{End}_R(R)$ notation and I was actually just on my way to ask this when I saw your comment. Again, thanks! I'll edit the question now. Hope that helps.

Comment: *the edit was to add the part about an "abelian group" in the title. It's funny how such small words can make a big difference :-)

Comment: @PineappleFish You should not ask the question only in the title. It should be clear in the post too. It is fine to be in both the title and post.  You should also consider removing some of the chattiness from the body... it's only contributing fluff to your post. It's enough to say you're a beginner to ring theory, that you don't know if this is true, and that you haven't been able to find an answer in google.  Ideally also you'd consider some examples and why you ruled them out, but I understand that's hard when you're a beginner.

Comment: @PineappleFish YOu'll find this and a lot of other advice that will improve your question (so that it will be insulated from closure and at the worst case deletion) [at this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335)

Comment: @rschwieb alright give me some time.

Comment: maybe a day or two. sorry i'm busy and there'r exams

Comment: I'll put here what I removed content-wise so it doesn't distract from the original question: "***personal note, of irrelevance to the actual question:* If it were true I'd have an easier time with things, and I think it would help me come to some personal understanding about rings, but I have no actual basis to believe it's true, and I am not advanced enough yet to know if I should attempt to prove it. But, I *will* come back to it in more depth if I know it's true and significant. Also, this isn't a homework question."

Comment: @rschwieb I fixed it. Thank you again.

Comment: This is an excellent question that appears to be pretty difficult.  I would guess the answer is no, based on the vague intuition that endomorphism rings tend to be "close to simple", but non-finitely generated abelian groups are weird and can do all sorts of weird things.

Comment: No it is not, @EricWofsey.  It could be, but this is a psq like all other psqs; this site ought not to be aristocratic.  New users are sometimes capable of writing better questions, per site expectations, than the questions from some more mature users, who write one sentence PSQs, with a "I have no clue" sort of second sentence, like this post is.

Comment: @amWhy What does psq mean?

Comment: Sorry, PineappleFish.  It is an acronym (on this site) from PSQ: a question that looks transcribed from assigned question, or an exercise from a text, whether or not it is an assignment.  It is a fine start, but much more context is needed.  Here's a good summary about [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C127.4632).  No one has to fulfill all suggestions, just "some" of them.

Comment: @amWhy oh wow I'm actually agreeing with you on something. Anyways, my original post had more context but then some people told me to take it out so I did (I think) as they said. And then idk why but it got a ton of upvotes, so yeah that's that ‍♂️.

Comment: Glad you included context; cheers! :)

Comment: @PineappleFish: The contradictory recommendations on context can be explained as follows.  You explained that the problem was interesting to _you_ in the question, but explained in the comments _why_ it was interesting in a way compelling to others.  SE sites are designed so that comments are ephemeral and questions should be written for future visitors.  Consequently, rschwieb recommended you remove the details about your perspective (because a future visitor isn't likely to care about you, sad to say)…and I've now moved the motivation from the comments into the question.

Comment: @JacobManaker Alright sounds cool with me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is "yes".

Every ring is a homomorphic image of the free ring $\mathbb{Z}\langle X\rangle$ generated by some sufficiently large set $X$. So it suffices to prove that $\mathbb{Z}\langle X\rangle$ is the endomorphism ring of some abelian group.

There may be a much more elementary way to show this, but it follows from the main theorem of

*Dugas, Manfred; Göbel, Rüdiger*, [**Every cotorsion-free algebra is an endomorphism algebra**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01182384), Math. Z. 181, 451-470 (1982). [ZBL0501.16031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0501.16031),

which (specialized from the more general context of modules for a Dedekind domain $R$ to the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$) states that every ring whose additive group is a cotorsion-free abelian group is the endomorphism ring of some abelian group.

Since the additive group of $\mathbb{Z}\langle X\rangle$ is a free abelian group, and therefore cotorsion-free, it follows that $\mathbb{Z}\langle X\rangle$ is the endomorphism ring of some abelian group.

Comment: Just to check - this *is* for rings and ring homomorphisms not rngs and rng homomorphisms right? This is a good answer btw.

Comment: Yes, rings with unity and homomorphisms that preserve the unity.